Understanding FHE bootstrapping: value of $q$ fed to lattice estimator
I am implementing OpenFHE. In the implementation I'm generating the modulus chain as shown in the example here. I am trying to run Lattice estimator for the same parameters in this example.
I wanted to confirm if $n=2^{16}$ and $q=2^{40}$. I say this because I see the value of $\log q$ to be $40$ which I assume is the size of the modulus chain.
Would the value of $q$ to be fed to lattice estimator $q=2^{40}$?
